# Why do anime characters nowadays tend to have very forward jaws?

Tags: anime-production, tropes, anime-history

For a healthy normal average human, it's common that their jaws are almost on the same vertical line as their foreheads. The jaws in this picture are more similar to jaws in real life:

(from *Seraph of the End: Battle in Nagoya*)
[image]

However, I have noticed a recent change in art style in the anime industry, that is, characters' jaws tend to be very forward, as is drawn in the following pictures:

(from *The Quintessential Quintuplets 2*)
[image]

(from *Kanojo mo Kanojo*)
[image]

(from *Mysteria Friends*)
[image]

(from *Detective Conan*)
[image]

A very good witness lies in the anime *Detective Conan*, whose early art style years ago didn't draw its characters' jaws so forward as today.

Why do anime characters nowadays tend to have very forward jaws? What causes this trend?

Comment: btw something interesting to note (I think?) it applies to both male and female characters - i'm not sure but you'd think this would be kinda ok for males but not really for females? or what? idk

Comment: Maybe because [anime characters are just cats](https://www.reddit.com/r/Animemes/comments/150gij1/anime_characters_are_just_cats/)?